# Rdl file view fullscreen

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, rdl

I am using ssrs reports in my project. I designed an rdl file in A4 size. My problem in when I see it in report viewer it appears very small compared to the screen width. So I'm wondering if there is any method to view rdl in screen width without affecting the page size??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the report-viewer control in your application, when the report is being accessed, you can set the following report-viewer propeties

```
reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.Normal);
reportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent;
```

you can test ZoomMode with either FullMode, PageWidth or Percent and see what works best in your scenerio

In one of my reports, i had issues with drilling back from the details report to the main report and used the snippet below to correct the display issues

```
private void reportViewer1_Back(object sender, BackEventArgs e)
    {
        reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.Normal);
        reportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent;
    }
```